# Reputation not changing over time though questions answered

Tags: support

For a couple of dates my reputation is not being updated. Do you have some policy on that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Looking at your profile](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/66236/sakhan?tab=answers&sort=newest), it seems you simply didn't get any upvotes on your recent answers, so they didn't net you any reputation.